# SharePoint 2010 and iPad jQuery Performance

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad

I've been working on a SharePoint 2010 site that utilizes jQuery.  jQuery is used almost everywhere on the site.  On an iPad or iPhone the jQuery animations work as they should but I'm not pleased with the performance.  Overall jQuery animations are laggy.  I've been searching for solutions to this problem and have come up with nothing.  Has anyone come across a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should use CSS transitions if you want them to be smooth. Javascript animations don't use the device's graphics hardware, while CSS transitions do. [This plugin](http://playground.benbarnett.net/jquery-animate-enhanced/) makes it much easier to use the appropriate type of animation for each user's device.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to play with jQuery animation settings like http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.fx.interval/